# Python: Trying to recompute class properties on changing variable

Tags: python, class, iteration

I am trying to write a CFD solver. I wanted to create a generic fluid "node" that would store properties and recompute its properties if it was assigned a new value to one of its properties (like temperature or pressure). Because this involves phase change, I would also like the existance of some properties to be dependent on one of the stored variables. So if the material is a gas, some additional properties exist and some go away versus if it was a liquid.

I've been trying for a about two days now to figure out some combination of set, get, and @property that will do what I need, but to no avail. This is my first post on stack overflow but I figured I had nothing to lose.

I've attempted some basic tutorials on get, set, and @properties. I have working (but spaghetti) code from a previous solver.

```py
class Fluid:
    def __init__(self, material, temperature, pressure, mdot, D_hydraulic, Flow_area):
        self.material    = material
        self.temperature = temperature      # K
        self.pressure    = pressure         # Pa
        self.mdot        = mdot             # m^3/s
        self.D_hydraulic = D_hydraulic      # m
        self.Flow_area   = Flow_area        # m^2

        if self.material in ["liquid", "fuel", "Monopropellant"]:
            self.density           = 1419 # Kg/m^3
            self.viscosity         = 0.125 # Kg/m*s
            self.cp                = 759.524 # J/Kg*K
            self.MW                = 0.1268 # Kg/mol
            self.k                 = 0.4 # W/m*K
            self.ignition_temp     = 388 # K
            self.Pr                = self.cp*self.viscosity/self.k

        if self.material in ["gas", "burnt"]:
            self.viscosity         = 1.48*10**-5 # Kg/m*s
            self.cp                = 2170.9 # J/Kg*K
            self.MW                = 20.819 # Kg/mol
            self.k                 = 0.3 # W/m*K
            self.gamma             = 1.218 # K
            self.R                 = 445 # J/Kg*K
            self.Pr                = 1
            self.T_combustion      = 1900 # K

            self.density           = self.pressure/(self.R*self.temperature) #Kg/m^3
            self.c                 = (self.gamma*self.R*self.temperature)

        self.Velocity = self.mdot/self.Flow_area # m/s
        self.Re = D_hydraulic*(self.Velocity)*self.density/self.viscosity

        if self.Re < 2300:
            self.Nu = 3.66
        elif self.Re >= 2300:
            self.Nu = 0.023*self.Re**(4/5)*self.Pr**(0.3)

        self.h = self.Nu*self.k/self.D_hydraulic #W/m^2*K
```

```
X=Fluid("liquid",100,1000,1,0.0004,0.0004)

X.density
Out[9]: 1419

X.material="gas"

X.density
Out[11]: 1419
```

I expected changing material from liquid to gas to recompute the density from the stored temperature/pressure/R value.

I know I would need something like @property, set, and/or get

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to do something like this:

```
class Fluid:
    def __init__(self, material, ...):
        self._material = material
        ...

    ...

    @property
    def material(self):
        return self._material

    @material.setter
    def material_setter(self, new_material):
        # Same logic that you have right now in the __init__
```

You define the material as a property & override the setter for it to run the logic that you have right now in the constructor. This should recompute the other properties as well.

Note: you can achieve this without `@property` as well, by overriding the `__setattr__` method and doing the recomputation if the attribute being set is 'material'

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you could do this (changed to `self.D_hydraulic`):

```
class Fluid:
    def __init__(self, material, temperature, pressure, mdot, D_hydraulic, Flow_area):
        self.material    = material
        self.temperature = temperature      # K
        self.pressure    = pressure         # Pa
        self.mdot        = mdot             # m^3/s
        self.D_hydraulic = D_hydraulic      # m
        self.Flow_area   = Flow_area        # m^2
        self.set_properties()

    def set_properties(self):
        if self.material in ["liquid", "fuel", "Monopropellant"]:
            self.density           = 1419 # Kg/m^3
            self.viscosity         = 0.125 # Kg/m*s
            self.cp                = 759.524 # J/Kg*K
            self.MW                = 0.1268 # Kg/mol
            self.k                 = 0.4 # W/m*K
            self.ignition_temp     = 388 # K
            self.Pr                = self.cp*self.viscosity/self.k

        if self.material in ["gas", "burnt"]:
            self.viscosity         = 1.48*10**-5 # Kg/m*s
            self.cp                = 2170.9 # J/Kg*K
            self.MW                = 20.819 # Kg/mol
            self.k                 = 0.3 # W/m*K
            self.gamma             = 1.218 # K
            self.R                 = 445 # J/Kg*K
            self.Pr                = 1
            self.T_combustion      = 1900 # K

            self.density           = self.pressure/(self.R*self.temperature) #Kg/m^3
            self.c                 = (self.gamma*self.R*self.temperature)

        self.Velocity = self.mdot/self.Flow_area # m/s
        self.Re = self.D_hydraulic*(self.Velocity)*self.density/self.viscosity

        if self.Re < 2300:
            self.Nu = 3.66
        elif self.Re >= 2300:
            self.Nu = 0.023*self.Re**(4/5)*self.Pr**(0.3)

        self.h = self.Nu*self.k/self.D_hydraulic #W/m^2*K
    def change_material(self, material):
        self.material=material
        self.set_properties()
```

which results in:

```
X=Fluid("liquid",100,1000,1,0.0004,0.0004)

X.density
Out: 1419

X.change_material('gas')

X.density
Out: 0.02247191011235955
```